# How to replace values in array using lodash when flag is true

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have JavaScript object:

```
myData = {
      items: [
        {
          flag: false,
          text: "good text"
        },
        {
          flag: true,
          text: "good text"
        },
        {
          flag: false,
          text: "good text"
        }
      ]
    }
```

How can I change text everywhere where `flag = true`.

For example only 2nd object need to be changed from `"good text"` to `"bad text"`, because only this object in my example has `flag = true`.

I want to do this using Lodash in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to use lodash, this should work:

```
_.forEach(myData.items, function (item) {
  if (item.flag) {
    item.text = 'bad text';
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this snippet to change the text.

```
myData.items = _.map(_.get(myData, 'items'), (item) => {
  if (item.flag) {
    item.text = "new text"
  }
  return item;
});
```

Comment: This will not work because item.flag datatype is number and you compare it to a string value.

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need lodash for this..

Here is a solution without using it

```
myData.items.forEach(item => item.text = item.flag ? "bad text" : item.text)
```

```js
const myData = {
      items: [
        {
          flag: false,
          text: "good text"
        },
        {
          flag: true,
          text: "good text"
        },
        {
          flag: false,
          text: "good text"
        }
      ]
    };

console.log(JSON.stringify(myData.items));

myData.items.forEach(item => item.text = item.flag ? "bad text" : item.text);

console.log(JSON.stringify(myData.items));
```

Answer (score 0):

How about: `_(myData.items).filter('flag').each(x => x.text='bad text');`

Comment: It works, but it will loop the list twice (first full list, then filtered list)

Comment: Hmm...are you sure, doesn't lodash use lazy evaluation when chaining functions (per the docs): https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#chain

Comment: Interestingly, depending on how many elements have flag set, the lodash version is faster. See: https://jsfiddle.net/1vxac6ex/1/. This is looping over 10 million records and setting flag to true when i%10 == 0. If we ALWAYS set flag, then your version is quite a bit faster. The "issue" with your version is that it's setting the property for every item, even when it doesn't need to. Ultimately, I like your version better. Using lodash doesn't make sense, but that's what the OP wanted. 

¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Wow, very interesting!